# Can't get this JavaScript to work on my dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

still working on that Dropdown menu. It's working for the most part, but I need to apply the same effect (closed when it loads, open upon click) to apply to the nested `<ul>`'s. I've tried a whole bunch of stuff, currently I tried applying the same script to the nested `<ul>` as I applied to the initial `<ul>`, but it does nothing. It opens as uncollapsed and does not respond correctly when clicked on. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown, 0);
dropdownArray.forEach(function (el) {
    var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'), menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'), arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');
    button.onclick = function (event) {
        if (!menu.hasClass('show')) {
            menu.classList.add('show');
            menu.classList.remove('hide');
            arrow.classList.add('open');
            arrow.classList.remove('close');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            menu.classList.remove('show');
            menu.classList.add('hide');
            arrow.classList.remove('open');
            arrow.classList.add('close');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
});
Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
    return this.className && new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(this.className);
};
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
  background: #C0C0C0;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
  content: '\25BC';
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li ul li {
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:80%;
  
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li ul li a{
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li ul li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown .show, .dropdown .hide {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html class="">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropstyle.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">Dropdown Menu</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Ga naar... <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Webdesign</a>
                 <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/web-design/eigen-website/">Website</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/cms/">CMS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
                  </ul>
         </li>
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Verkoop</a>
             <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/verkoop/computer-laptops">Computers & laptops</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/verkoop/bullguard-virusscanner-backup">Bullguard anti-virus & backup</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/reparatie/">Reparatie</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Google diensten</a>
              <ul> 
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/google-diensten/adwords">Adwords</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/google-diensten/drive">Drive</a></li>            
              </ul>  
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Glasvezel</a>
              <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/glasvezel-baarn/introductie">Introductie</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/glasvezel-baarn/waarom">Waarom</a></li>   
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/glasvezel-baarn/techniek">Techniek</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/glasvezel-baarn/aanmelden">Aanmelden</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/nieuws-overzicht/">Nieuws</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.breunesse-ict.nl/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="dropscript.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Where have you seen jQuery in this code?

Comment: I imported the jquery at the bottom of the HTML document.

Comment: Perhaps but you are not using it in the question - you are even extending the element prototype to not use jQuery. jQuery toggleClass would save a lot of code

Comment: Then, why don't you use it?)))

Comment: Oh... Sorry if that's dumb. i only learned about Jquery last week. is it better to leave it out for now, then? (I'm a second year app developer student, not an experienced programmer. Sorry if I get confused sometimes.)

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of code for a simple dropdown menu

Comment: It's got a lot of animations. try running the code to see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `dropdown`, `dropdown-menu` classes to the sub dropdown structures too, and also include the arrow there too. It seems like it's missing. So now this is happening:

- You get only the first `li` in the beginning.
- You query only the first `a` in it, and only the first `ul`.
- Thus you handle the clicks and dropdowns only at first level.

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gdna2ncq/1/

Comment: Thank you, this solved half of my problem. Now the dropdown opens neatly but the sub dropdowns won't open at all anymore. Any idea how I could fix that problem?

Comment: Could you please put the code on jsfiddle.net to let me have a try there? I can't edit it here to test.

Comment: You should add the `dropdown-menu` class to the nested `ul`'s too, and also include the arrows in every level for proper working I guess.

Comment: That's what I did. And yes, I'll upload the code to jsfiddle.net. Give me one minute.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! You didn't need to add those arrows but I appreciate the effort. :)

Comment: Yes, technically didn't but users should know somehow that those are dropdowns as well. :)

Comment: That's true but the entire arrow is going away and instead I'm making a more classic menu button. I also want to get rid of the animation and make the motion more like a slide, nothing fancy. The point is to make it as close to the dropdown on http://www.veermanict.nl/ (in mobile resolution, it's a fusion thing) as possible. And the motion takes up a lot of code. As does the arrow thingy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89145/discussion-between-really-loud-girl-and-zoltan-tamasi).